# Why not seek shelter in the inner compartments of the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

We all know that Starfleet designs its starships so that the crew can enjoy the miraculous wonders that empty space has to offer. Take the 1701-D for an example. They position the bridge in [vulnerable places](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114505/32435), offer a nice observation lounge for senior staff meetings, have Ten Forward for recreation and the occasional great stately dinner, and also have many a crew quarter featuring a scenic view. There are certain drawbacks to that however that have been discussed before.

In times of danger however, such as the power outage in episode [TNG 1x05 The Last Outpost](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Last_Outpost) would it not be wise to retreat to the inner compartments of the ship? Due to the power loss the ship is reported to cool down but *physics tells us* that a spherical* spaceship put into the vacuum of space loses heat by radiation only. Obviously the inner parts of the ship could maintain higher temperature levels for a longer time while heat is transmitted to the outer shell by means of heat conduction (and convection if you will). Are there really no shelters burried in deep the belly of the ship?

---

<sup><sub>* I think that we can safely assume the shape of the Enterprise to be spherical.</sub></sup>

Comment: Enterprise is a sphere?

Comment: You have heard of the spherical chicken in a vacuum? The idea is the same, spherical or not, the thermal energy needs to travel to the outside first before it could be lost to space, thus being near to the core helps against freezing to death too soon (if just a little).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Due to the power loss the ship is reported to cool down but physics tells us that a spherical* spaceship put into the vacuum of space loses heat by radiation only.
>
> * I think that we can safely assume the shape of the Enterprise to be spherical.

Clearly the Enterprise is NOT a sphere.

[image]

Regardless, there are inner compartments deeper inside the hull.

In fact, as part of the survival measures, as life support is failing...all energy is diverted to the **family decks** to extend their survival.

[**Memory Alpha Link**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Outpost)

Comment: Good catch on the diversion of the energy part, still on the show it is depicted that Troy, Crusher and the Captain get the chill while enjoying the view. As for the spherical thing, well, I guess I just thought that a science joke would resonate well with the nerdy people around here. Turns out I was wrong.